# Ag-grid - Events and Methods (Vuejs)

Tags: vue.js, events, ag-grid

I can't use the "save" method to save a change to my table data

I am using the "cellValueChanged" method to edit and save a table cell.

```
<ag-grid-vue :cellValueChanged="save"></ag-grid-vue>

methods: {
    save() {
        const method = this.instituicao.id ? 'put' : 'post'
        const id = this.instituicao.id ? `/${this.instituicao.id}` : ''
        axios[method](`${baseApiUrl}/instituicao${id}`, this.instituicao)
            .then(() => {
                this.$toasted.global.defaultSuccess()
                this.reset()
            })
            .catch(showError)
},
```

Error message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9MT7.png)

Comment: Did you try console.log of this.instituicao which seems to be undefined

Comment: Yes, I was able to view institution data:

    mounted() {
        this.columnDefs = [
            {headerName: 'ID', field: 'id', filter: false, editable: true},
            {headerName: 'Código do Banco', field: 'codigo', filter: false, editable: true},
            {headerName: 'Nome do Banco', field: 'nome', filter: false, editable: true}
        ];
        axios.get(`${baseApiUrl}/instituicao`)
            .then(({data}) => this.rowData = data)
    },

Comment: Try using this.instituicao & instituicao.id

Comment: which line of code?

Comment: const method = this.instituicao & instituicao.id? 'put' : 'post'

Comment: the same mistake happened

Comment: const method = this.instituicao && this.instituicao.id ? 'put' : 'post'
        const id = this.instituicao && this.instituicao.id ? `/${this.instituicao.id}` : ''

Comment: use in both places

Comment: Now another error has occurred: POST http://localhost:4000/instituicao 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: that issue is related to API , parameters infor or API URL issue which is causing that bad request error

Comment: Error occurs because "id" is not appearing in url, post method is done through id

Comment: Not storing or id in constant:

const id = this.instituicao && this.instituicao.id ? `/${this.instituicao.id}` : ''

Comment: confused now , you are checking id and if not available doing POST and your post requires id

Comment: I perform the "post" method through the table id

http://prntscr.com/pw18v0

Comment: Is it possible to pass or publish by database table ID?

Comment: @NagaSaiA This "save" method I was using with bootstrap-vue, now on ag-grid I don't know how I could use a POST method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use event callback of @cell-value-changed

1. Change your event to @cell-value-changed = "save"
2. Use event callback to get old and new values of cell

`save(event) {
                    console.log('onCellValueChanged: ' + event.oldValue + ' to ' + event.newValue);
                }`

3. Get required id value from that event callback and use it for POST call

Comment: I was able to apply the POST method using axios, through the request parameters:

axios [method] (`$ {baseApiUrl} / institution / $ {event.data.id}`, event.data)

How could I apply a method on multiple lines?